# Vuex and vue best practise questions

Tags: vue.js, vuex

1 I see a some times that a vuex action collects information from other vuex modules using dispatch from other modules. With this it looses its "modulair" flexibility. What is the best practise in this case?

2 Also do you agree that Vue components needs to be kept clean from alot of fetch and formcheck logic and better move this logic to vuex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. isolate the common code between 2 modules into a pure function, then import this function in both modules. You can even use a Class with static methods.
2. yes, Vue components should be a pure presentation/view layer - the logic must stay into reusable non-visual classes. The form validation checks are especially suitable for pure functions. And fetches could be extracted as static methods into separate Service class (or several such classes, if you want to follow the Modules pattern).